# Django: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime' error on assigning DateField to a variable in a model class method

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Blog` model method that create a unique serial number based on the blog's `submission_date`, `submission_time`, and `id` of the blog instance.
The Blog model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    serial_no = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    submit_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    submit_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    ...
```

In the method, I'm taking the date and time fields and converting them to strings through `strftime()`, then concatenating them. This is the method:

```
def get_serial_no(self):
    s_date = self.submit_date
    s_time = self.submit_time
    str_date = s_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    str_time = s_time.strftime('%H%m')
    serial = self.id + str_date + str_time
    return serial
```

I am overriding the `save()` method to populate slug and serial_no field. The error is only occurring when I'm saving an article. It's pointing to this line: `str_date = s_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')`; with the error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime'`.

As far as I understand I am properly referencing to the Date type. Therefore, it should call its `strftime()` function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `auto_now=True` only sets the value when the object is saved, before then the field will not have a value

Comment: Isn't overriding save() solving the problem? i.e. putting value in serial_no and then saving?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `serial_no` field? Does it need to be saved to the DB or can it be a property?

Comment: You need to do something like `self.submit_date = self.submit_date or timezone.now()` in your save method and remove `auto_now`. As you need the value before the object is saved

Comment: Simply change `auto_now_add=True` and it will work